# Installing Language Filter and Language Code system plugins

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, language, multilingual, system-plugin

I have a Joomla website (which I didn't install myself) that seems to be lacking the system plugins "Language Filter" and "Language Code". It seems like it wasn't installed as a multi-language site in the first place (I assume) so that might explain why these two plugins are missing (or maybe that I just fail to find them).

My question is : how can I install these two plugins on an existing Joomla website ?

I am using Joomla 3.8.7

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Ok my bad, they were installed. I failed to find them because their names were translated into French in the administration panel...

Comment: Please accept your own answer as the solution by clicking on the tick icon under the downvote icon so others can see that this question is resolved. Thank-you.